# What neural network loss function to use for multi-class, multi-label classification tasks where labels refer to counts?

Tags: neural-networks, classification, gradient-descent, loss-functions

I would like to train a neural network to detect which of N classes is present, and in what amounts. In other words each example **x** has label vector **y** where **y_i >= 0**.

For example, this could be an image classifier that detects not only whether a given object is present, but **how many instances** of that object are in the image. For example a classifier trained to detect trucks, dogs, and trees might be given an image with 1 truck, 2 dogs, and 0 trees, and I'd like the prediction to reflect the actual counts.

Binary Cross Entropy is close, but only accounts for detecting the presence of a class, not counting it.

Comment: Perhaps I should be using regression?

Comment: Welcome to the site! This seems like a tricky problem. Have you checked what people have done in the past on similar problems?

Comment: I suppose in practice, I don't really need exact counts. Getting close enough, or just having relative amounts would be fine. Also, any given count would be limited to a relatively small number, say no more than 10 or 20.

Comment: Look at crowd counting literature